# How to use comparison with argc

Tags: c++

I'm making a cowsay program. When you type cowsay.exe "text" in the console, a message is displayed with a cow.

But, if there is more than one argument, I want the program to stop.

```
if(argc > 1 || argc < 1)
{
    cout << "ERROR" << endl;
}
```

but it doesn't work, thanks for help!

Comment: please post the main function declaration, are you declaring argc correctly? Also what you did is only print to console, maybe you want to return -1; after the cout?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not enough detailed. What is the expected behaviour? What you get, instead?

Comment: Be aware that the program name itself is typically passed as the first entry in `argv`, and `argc == 1` if there's no other values in `argv`.  If you say `cowsay.exe text`, `argc` should be **2**.

Comment: A better comparison would be `if( argc != 1 )`.

Comment: My apologize, in fact, the correct code is: if(argc > 2) ... Thanks and sorry ^^

Comment: It is not relevant to the question, but `argc > 1 || argc < 1` can be written as `argc != 1`. Moreover `argc < 1` is always false, so you can also write `argc > 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your parameter count should be 2, since one of them is 'cowsay.exe' and the other one is 'text'.

```
if(argc != 2)
{
  cout << "ERROR" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**use:**

```
if(argc !=1)
{
    cout << "ERROR" << endl;
    return false;
}
```

**Note :** argc is the count of arguments

The main function of a C++ program has two parameters, by convention named argc and argv, which give it the command-line arguments used to launch the program.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept no more than one argument, you should be comparing your argument count as such::

```
if( argc != 2 )
```

This is because, the first argument is always the name of executable you are calling and the next are the arguments which you pass to your executable.
From the [link](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html),

> The array of character pointers is the listing of all the arguments.
>   argv[0] is the name of the program, or an empty string if the name is
>   not available. After that, every element number less than argc is a
>   command line argument. You can use each argv element just like a
>   string, or use argv as a two dimensional array. argv[argc] is a null
>   pointer.